# Waiting time for editor's decision

Tags: phd, paper-submission, editors

I resubmitted a manuscript to a journal (listed in political science as well as in International Relations and Economics journal rankings). The editor's decision was minor revisions. The email says that after resubmitting, the final decision will be made by the editor's team asap (asap=as soon as possible). My re-submission was more than 6 weeks ago. 
I was wondering how long I should wait until I approach the editor and ask about the decision without being rude and impatient? 
My question is also spurred by the fact that I am PhD student who writes a cumulative dissertation and thereby, accepted (or even published) manuscripts are important ;) 
 
Any experiences, advices or recommendations are very welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After six weeks you can probably ask, but don't ask repeatedly. Just explain that the paper is important to you as a component of your dissertation. You don't need a long explanation or a plea for exceptional treatment.

Depending on the journal, six weeks may be an instant in time. But it is long enough that it is reasonable to ask. If they are overly busy, however, your question may take a while to answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the decision letter implied a decision will be made quickly, and if the revisions you were asked for are truly minor, six weeks is way too long. I'd ask for an update after 2 weeks.

I note that the decision letter said the "editor's team" is the one making the decision, which makes it sound like the editor's decision was actually "accept on resubmission regardless of what is submitted". It's possible the journal's staff aren't aware of this and are waiting for the editor to make a decision; meanwhile the editor isn't looking at the manuscript anymore because he thinks he's already finished handling it. Either way, I'd write in to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Thats just the nature of journals sometimes. You never know what is going on that might delay the editor's decision. Is it within the time frame of a major conference? Is there another editorial issue that is taking up time? Did one of the editors have a major life event? Or any other possibilities that might cause a delay.

To give a recent example of a journal in my field:
The journal decided to request submission for a special issue. The subject of this special issue caused a little bit of an uproar. This led to some amount of turmoil as the editors needed to deal with the uproar from senior members of the editorial board. This led to delayed decisions on some manuscripts.

If push does come to shove though, you might be better served having your adviser reach out. During graduate school, I had a colleague who was in a similar situation as you. Our mutual adviser, a prominent member of the field, was the one who reached out to the journal to find out what was going on. With a little pushing from our adviser, things starting moving forward with the manuscript.

In other words, I would not worry too much. Focus on other writing would be my advice.