# Status of my revised manuscript: editor decision changed to under review

Tags: publications, peer-review

Two monts ago, I submitted a manuscript (Scholarone Manuscripts).
I got major revisions and implemented ALL of them. Then I re-submitted my manuscript. After two days the status changed to under review. Then after five days the status changed to awaiting editor decision and then after two more days I saw my status change to under review again (today is the 3rd day with this status).

Any idea what is happening?

Comment: I forgot. Also with my article, (revised version) I submitted a 4 pages pdf in which I explained everything that I did in my revised version). Just to help the referees and the editor who handle my manuscript.

Comment: See this: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/124525/72855

Comment: It just seems like the editor's decision was to get more advice from reviewers; maybe the same ones, or possibly new.

Comment: @buffy That is almost certainly the case. This recently happened where I was asked to review a manuscript after a round of revisions due to the technical nature of the papers methods.

Comment: So, you believe that the manuscript is back to the reviewers again? But why? The editor disagree? Or...there is a misunderstanding between them?

Comment: Only the editor can tell you _why_. It is permissible to ask. It is also permissible to _not_ panic.